# unit test error, Quasar Drawer (QDrawer) $layout.totalWidth is undefined Vue 3

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar, vitest

I'm trying to create this unit test in Vue Js 3

**Unit Test**

```
        render(Paragraph, {
            props: {analise: analise, textosAutuacao: autuacao},
            global: {
                plugins: [Quasar]
            }
        })
        await fireEvent.click(await screen.getByTestId("paragrafoPadrao"))
        await fireEvent.click(await screen.getByLabelText("Choose default paragraph"))

    })
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
 ❯ setup node_modules/quasar/src/components/drawer/QDrawer.js:88:62
     86|     const belowBreakpoint = ref(
     87|       props.behavior === 'mobile'
     88|       || (props.behavior !== 'desktop' && $layout.totalWidth.value <= props.breakpoint)
       |                                                              ^
     89|     )
     90|
```

**Component**

```
...
<div v-if="origemParagrafoPadrao === 'previo'">
    <div>
      <q-btn @click="drawerParagrafoPadrao = !drawerParagrafoPadrao" dense no-caps color="primary" label="Escolher parágrafo padrão" class="q-my-md" icon-right="arrow_right"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <q-card flat bordered v-for="texto in selecaoTextoAutuacao" :key="texto.id">
        <q-card-section>
          <div class="flex">
            <h6 class="text-subtitle2 text-weight-bold">{{ texto.id }} - {{ texto.titulo }}</h6>
            <a class="q-link text-primary cursor-pointer q-ml-xs" :id="'lnkExcluirTextoJurisprudencia' + texto.id"
                @click="excluirTextoParagrafoPadrao(texto)">
              ( Excluir )
            </a>
          </div>
          <div v-html="texto.texto" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>
        </q-card-section>
      </q-card>
    </div>
    <q-drawer v-model="drawerParagrafoPadrao" side="right" :breakpoint="10" bordered  class="shadow-2 rounded-borders" :width="900">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center q-ma-md">
...
```

The question is how can I do this unit test using vitest and when rendering the q-drawer the above error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Quasars `q-drawer` component must be wrapped in a `q-layout` component:

```
<q-layout>
    <q-drawer></q-drawer>
</q-layout>
```

The Quasar docs don't really jump out and tell you it's necessary, but if you reread them it's heavily implied (and all the examples use that pattern). https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer